Error 500 in Next.js Image Optimizer After Docker Build: "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000"
I am working on a Next.js application and encountering an issue after building it in Docker. The server runs on port 9000, and the frontend runs on port 3000. The images are loaded properly in the Next.js avatar tag, but they do not appear in the Image component. Instead, I get a 500 Internal Server Error.
Error Message:
GET http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9000%2Fuploads%2Fpublic%2Fbanners%2F1725328558480-LoneSamuraiSekiroWallpapers.jpg&w=1920&q=75 500 (Internal Server Error)
GET http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9000%2Fuploads%2Fpublic%2Fprofile-pictures%2F1725328558477-SamuraAndRaven.jpg&w=1920&q=75 500 (Internal Server Error)

TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13179:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
    at async fetchExternalImage (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/image-optimizer.js:580:17)
    ...
[cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000

Configuration:
Next.js next.config.js file:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "http",
        hostname: "127.0.0.1",
        port: "9000",
        pathname: "/uploads/**",
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default nextConfig;


Image Component Usage:
<Image
  src={encodeURI(baseUrl + banner)}
  alt={`${name}'s banner`}
  objectFit="cover"
  layout="fill"
/>

Additional Information:
I can view the images directly in the browser by visiting the URLs.
The image optimizer fails with an ECONNREFUSED error when the Next.js app tries to fetch images from the backend.
Both services are running in Docker containers.
What I Have Tried:
Ensured that the server is accessible and running properly on port 9000.
Confirmed that the images load properly in the browser.
Docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    container_name: postgres-freetube-container
    ports:
      - "5432:5432" # Expose PostgreSQL port
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: freetube
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - freetube_network

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:9000" # Expose the backend port
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://user:password@db:5432/freetube?schema=public" # Use the db service name as the host
      PORT: 9000
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: >
      sh -c "npx prisma migrate deploy && npm start"
    networks:
      - freetube_network

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./freetube
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" # Expose the frontend port
    environment:
      NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL: "http://backend:9000/api/" # Reference the backend service
      NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL: "http://backend:9000/"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - freetube_network
    # env_file:
    #   - .env # Ensure the .env file is correctly referenced

volumes:
  db_data:

networks:
  freetube_network:
    driver: bridge

Question:
How can I resolve the "connect ECONNREFUSED" error in the Next.js image optimizer when fetching images from my backend server after building in Docker? Is there something wrong with the configuration or the way the containers are set up?

I think you are facing "ECONNREFUSED" error in your Next.js app because your Next.js Image component is trying to fetch images from the backend server using 127.0.0.1:9000. However, inside Docker, 127.0.0.1 refers to the container itself, not your host machine or other containers.
What you can try is to ensure that both your frontend and backend services are on the same Docker network, and then use the service name instead of 127.0.0.1 in your next.config.js and when building the image URL in your component
Like below:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
  {
        protocol: "http",
        hostname: "backend", // Use the service name here
        port: "9000",
        pathname: "/uploads/**",
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default nextConfig;


As soon as I do that all my APIs give err connection refused. I will update the question with my docker-compose file.
Also, note the website is served on the host machine, that is why all the APIs work. In my question I have mentioned that my website can access the images in an avatar tag.
